# Lock project in Visual Source Safe as ReadOnly

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe

We are currently migrating our projects to TFS over a period of around 6 months.

We are not migrating history, instead we are just unbinding the projects from Source Safe and then adding them to TFS.

Is it possible to somehow lock the projects in Source Safe so that no one can accidentally checkout a project in Source Safe rather than TFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if some projects must remain in ss (is there a good reason why you shouldn't just switch to tfs? Especially as you can migrate the entire DB including the history in one easy go?) then some options might be:

- individual users can get properties on folders in ss and Cloak the folder so ss effectively ignores it.
- you could set exclusive check-outs and get one user (possibly a new user for this purpose) to check out any files that you have migrated.
- simply delete migrated files in ss. The history is still there and they are being developed in tfs, so why keep them live in ss at all?